# How to label roads like this in QGIS 2.18.14?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I got roads from OSM, and have labeled with the 'name' field. This suit me.

But, how to label like this screenshot, with this rectangle label? The content is in the 'ref' field.
[image]

Comment: with the "background" option in labels dialog

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the label options, then select the `background` tab and select to draw a rectangular buffer of the proper color around the labels.

[image]